# Parsing xml with xstream in java (android studio)

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, xstream

Something is wrong and application crashes. I am trying to parse `xml` text into java classes, I'm using `XStream` library. Code crashes after I use method `fromXML`. My code:

XML file looks like this:

```
<FilesManifest>
<Group>
    <HeaderName>Pirmas hdr</HeaderName>
    <Type>theory</Type>
    <Piece>
        <FileName>11.txt</FileName>
        <HeadLine>hi1</HeadLine>
    </Piece>
    <Piece>
        <FileName>22.txt</FileName>
        <HeadLine>hi2</HeadLine>
    </Piece>
</Group>

<Group>
    <HeaderName>antras hdr</HeaderName>
    <Type>theory</Type>
    <Piece>
        <FileName>33.txt</FileName>
        <HeadLine>hi3</HeadLine>
    </Piece>
    <Piece>
        <FileName>44.txt</FileName>
        <HeadLine>hi4</HeadLine>
    </Piece>
</Group>

<Group>
    <HeaderName>tracias hdr</HeaderName>
    <Type>test</Type>
    <Piece>
        <FileName>55.txt</FileName>
        <HeadLine>hi5</HeadLine>
    </Piece>
    <Piece>
        <FileName>66.txt</FileName>
        <HeadLine>hi6</HeadLine>
    </Piece>
</Group>
</FilesManifest>
```

My main function code:

```
String fileText = ReadFile();
XStream xstream = new XStream();

xstream.alias("FilesManifest", MyFileManager.class);
xstream.alias("Group", MyGroup.class);
xstream.alias("Piece", MyPiece.class);

MyFileManager data = (MyFileManager)xstream.fromXML(fileText);
```

And classes for xml parsing:

```
public class MyFileManager {
    public List<MyGroup> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }

    public void setGroups(List<MyGroup> groups) {
        this.groups = groups;
    }
    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "group")
    private List<MyGroup> groups = new ArrayList<MyGroup>();
}

public class MyGroup {
    private String headerName;
    private String type;

    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "piece")
    private List<MyPiece> pieces = new ArrayList<MyPiece>();

    public List<MyPiece> getPieces() {
        return pieces;
    }

    public void setPieces(List<MyPiece> pieces) {
        this.pieces = pieces;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getHeaderName() {
        return headerName;
    }

    public void setHeaderName(String headerName) {
        this.headerName = headerName;
    }

}

public class MyPiece {
    private String fileName;
    private String headLine;

    public String getHeadLine() {
        return headLine;
    }

    public void setHeadLine(String headLine) {
        this.headLine = headLine;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
}
```

So can you advice me that code would work correctly? Maybe there is other way to parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could make your code work by fixing 2 main issues:

1. Your mapping is incomplete and not correct because you seem to forget that `XML` is **case-sensitive** which means that for example `@XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "group")` should be `@XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "Group")` and all the fields must be annotated with `@XStreamAlias` to provide an alias with the first character in capital.
2. You did not call [`processAnnotations(Class type)`](http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream.html#processAnnotations-java.lang.Class-) such that your annotations are not processed.

So at the end your code should be something like that:

Your POJOs:

```
public class MyFileManager {
    ...
    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "Group")
    private List<MyGroup> groups = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class MyGroup {
    @XStreamAlias("HeaderName")
    private String headerName;
    @XStreamAlias("Type")
    private String type;

    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "Piece")
    private List<MyPiece> pieces = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
}

public class MyPiece {
    @XStreamAlias("FileName")
    private String fileName;
    @XStreamAlias("HeadLine")
    private String headLine;

    ...
}
```

Your main function code:

```
...
// Process the provided annotations
xstream.processAnnotations(MyFileManager.class);
MyFileManager data = (MyFileManager)xstream.fromXML(fileText);
```

Comment: I searched myself this fix 2hours :D, thnks